# QM: Invalid property name

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am running Windows 10 using Qt Creator ver 4.15.1 as shown in the image below.[image]

I have an Android kit which was auto-detected during installation which is called Android Qt 5.15.0 Clang. When I create a Qt Quick Application I get an error as follows:

C:\Qt\5.15.0\android\mkspecs\features\android\android_deployment_settings.prf:78:
error: contains(): Encountered invalid regular expression '.*\qmake_qmake_immediate.qrc$'.

This is the code in my main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10


Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

}
```

For every property defined under Window, I get a specific error that says "Invalid property name". If I choose a different kit (such as a desktop based one), the error goes away.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest 5.15.x?

Comment: I have just installed a fresh copy of 5.15.2 and have posted a new question because, immediately after the installation, I am not able to start Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ApplicationWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html) instead of `Window`.